# Why when I open a submenu page scroll up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a menu for the mobile, that when I click on an item in a submenu appears. The problem is that if I do this when the page is scrolled a bit, the page scrolls back up ... (whether open or close the submenu).

This obviously does not happen when the page is not scrolled

This is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/qsq4y9d8/3/

this a css of submenu item

```
.lisottomenu {
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    display: block;   
    background: #E4BF85;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style-type: none;   
    width:100%;  
}
```

this css of item parent

```
ul li.leaf {
    background: #646464 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    display: block;
     font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
     list-style-type: none;
     position: relative;
 }
```

This is the problem:

[image]

(the problem is the auto-scroll)

I hope you can help me, even though the code is a bit long and I do not write well in English ...

Comment: It doesn't scroll up, it is a browser natural behaviour : when suddenly a page can contain the whole stuff after being scrollable, it comes back to the initial state () which make it appear like a scroll up

Comment: Are those `<a>` links? do they have a `#` href? it could be scrolling because of something like that

Comment: i don't understand... see this website by mobile https://unata.com/ if i open a submenu and after with firebug i hidden the submenu (display:none) the page doesn.'t scroll.... however are links in my jsfiddle

Comment: @ntgCleaner yes are links...

Comment: @ntgCleaner yoy are the best! the problem was that those are links with "#" if you post an ask i will accept it

Comment: @user3162975, You got it! I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment:

Any `<a>` with an href containing a "#" places a `#` in the URL which in turn looks for an empty anchor.  Since one doesn't exist, it defaults to scrolling to the top.

Remove the "#" from your links and it won't scroll to the top anymore

Change

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="">Link</a>
```

and it should stop scrolling to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sub menu is making the entire window higher, so it has to make this scroll just when you are closing the sub-menu.

It is just how the browser reacts to this kind of height change.

One solution would to give the side menu defined max-height, and overflow-y:scroll.

```
#content, #sidebar-first {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 370px;
}
```

This way, when the the sidemenus are opening it wont affected the height of the document.

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qsq4y9d8/9/

Comment: No, the problem is also open the submenu of item "madagascar": scroll the page and click the item than click another times to close it and the page auto scroll :( why ?????? the submenu "madagascar"not making the entire window higher

Answer (score 0):

You have so many elements being created and removed and styles erased and added to the elements every time the menu is clicked, I think the browser just tries to refresh the layout or something.

Try adding and removing classes that show and hide your sub menus, and have your elements in your html from the start, instead of creating and destroying so much (unless they need to be dynamically generated from the server or something)